# Is it possible to use Composer to manage Wordpress databases?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, composer-php

I am trying to use Composer for my Wordpress workflow and was wondering if there is a way for Composer to grab a MySQL database from my S3 bucket? The idea here is that I want to develop Wordpress websites locally starting from a backup copy of a database. Was hoping to find a way to automate this through Composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom [scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) for composer, and tell it what you want to do.

For example, if you wanted to pull it from S3 and import it using the `mysql` command line utility, you could add something like this to `composer.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "refresh-db": "aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/db-dump.sql /tmp/db-dump.sql && mysql -hlocalhost -uroot my_db_name < /tmp/db-dump.sql"
}
```

Then run `composer refresh-db` to execute it.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure that I follow you correctly the script goes: 1.list bucket/object location 2.set path for local directory 3. set db name 4. confirm path for local directory?

Comment: It's just an example, but it has two commands. The first one copies an object from S3 to your `/tmp` folder, the second command imports that DB dump file as the root user into `my_db_name` where the MySQL server is localhost and there's no root user password. Purely an example - you can put any bash commands in there.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining, very helpful